# Не работает камера в vuforia

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, vuforia

Вроде у меня всё в unity для работы с vuforia настроено, но когда я запускаю проект появляется это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я даже запускал проект на другом ПК и там всё работало
Как думаете с чем это связанно?

Comment: Здравствуй, а вуфорию настроил ?(ну там лицензию в файл конфигураций)И врубить поддержку в настройках проекта.

Comment: Совсем забыл про ваш комментарий. Оказывается проблема была всего лишь в том, что я не включил камеру на своём ПК

Comment: Ничего, главное что пофиксили, ет хорошо. Удачи с вуфорией вам.